# val() returning html() instead of undefined for <option> tag when no value attribute is set

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value="hasAttr">Has a value attr</option>
    <option>Does not have a value attr</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, one of the options has a value attribute set and the other does not. However, when I go to check the `val()` for each of the options via jQuery, the option that does not have a value attribute set is returning the text inside of the  tag (`html()`) instead of `undefined` as I would normally expect.

```
var $select = $('select');

$select.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $options = $this.children('option');

    $options.each(function(){
        var $option = $(this),
            $value  = $option.val(),
            $html   = $option.html();

        console.log('Option Value: '+ $value +'\nOption HTML: '+ $html);

    });

});
```

Even if I change the code to look for `$option.attr('value')`, I still get the same results. Is there a way that I can check to see if an `<option>` has a `value` attribute present that will return boolean?

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cVJux/).

---

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cVJux/2/) with solution.

Comment: If you don't want the option to have a value, you need to use `<option value="">No Value</option>`, and even then, it actually has a value of empty string (`""`), which is conceptually different than no value (`null`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is correct, standard behaviour. In the absence of a `value` attribute, the textual content of the element is used as the element's value.

From the [W3C website](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option):

> If there isn't [a value attribute], the value of an option element is the textContent of the element.

---

You can test for the presence of the content attribute using `getAttribute` on the DOM node:

```
$option[0].getAtribute('value') // returns null
```

Alternatively, you can use the jQuery `is` method with the "has-attribute" selector:

```
$option.is('[value]') // returns false
```

Comment: Understood, but that doesn't really answer the question. Is there a way that I can check for the value attribute that returns true or false for an option depending on if the attribute is actually set or not?

Comment: You can also use [hasAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.hasAttribute) if you just want a boolean value.

Comment: Thanks, using the `.is('[value]')` works as needed. Just a note, `.is('[val]')` returns false for both in this example but `'[value]'` works as expected.

Comment: Indeed, typo on my part - sorry! But to note: really you should play by standard behaviour, not use tricks to avoid it.